# jQuery DataTables v1.10 + Rails ajax data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

RailsCasts [episode 340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables) on DataTables was interesting, but with the release of DataTables v1.10, lots have changed. Ajax is simpler but API's are easier to configure. Does anyone have examples of **Rails code** that creates Ajax data for DataTables? It'll be useful if it can be used for sorting, searching, in addition to pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very useful for sorting ,searching and also pagination both for client side as well as serverside but not at the same time.
It is a very good plugin(gem), I have used it.
 Example:-Ajax data for datatable

```
var table = $("#example_id").DataTable({

    iDisplayLength: 100,
    bInfo: false,
    bSort: true,
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    bStateSave: true,
    bDestroy: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: true,
    bFilter: false,
    sAjaxSource: '/example/action_name',
    fnServerParams: function (aoData) {
        aoData.push(
            { "name": "example1", "value": $("#_example1").val() },
            { "name": "example2", "value": 5 },
            { "name": "example3", "value": "My Name" }
        );
    },
    oLanguage:{
        sZeroRecords: "No records found."},
    "sDom": 'rtlfip'

});
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Do you also have server side (Rails) example?

Comment: Server side (Rails) example? I didnt get you..for datatable?

Comment: Rails server side example to provide the JSON/ajax results needed that Datatable can consume.

Comment: Yes, I can give example  $.ajax({
            url: '/example/search_result',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false,
            data:data_params,
            success: function (data){
                table.fnDraw();
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                console.log("Error in sending data");
            }
        });